# Fade Windows Desktop in C++

Tags: c++, windows, screen-capture

I am trying to work out how to fade out or dim the Windows Desktop and then display a rectangular portion of the desktop normally. This is for a screen area capture program. You can see the precise effect I am after in [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/)  Fading the background in a Web page is also commonly done. Any tips/pointers/C++ source much appreciated. Google has not helped so far.

Thanks,
Neville

Comment: Nevf, I am doing now close thing that you do, can you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431612/how-to-show-semitransparent-window-above-all-windows/32432473#32432473

Comment: I don't know how to make it such a way that windows under this our semitransparent top most screen were editable and clickable? prntscr.com/8dkvvw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a layered window that covers the entire screen, but paint it with color key values such that the rectangular region of interest (the area that should be undarkened) is filled entirely with the color key. This region will then be completely transparent, and not darkened like the rest of the desktop. The rest of your layered window should be set to have a constant alpha value that is mostly transparent and filled with a dark color.

Here's a complete, working example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ScreenCapper.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

const COLORREF transparentColor = RGB(255,0,0); // Pure red is the color key, or totally transparent color
const BYTE overallTranparencyAmount = 90; // Out of 255
int DesktopWidth,DesktopHeight;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPTSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    DesktopWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    DesktopHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_SCREENCAPPER, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SCREENCAPPER));

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    memset(&wcex,0,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SCREENCAPPER));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    //wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SCREENCAPPER);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, szWindowClass, szTitle,WS_POPUP, 0, 0, DesktopWidth, DesktopHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,transparentColor,32,LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    if (message == WM_COMMAND)
    {
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    else if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        HBRUSH hDarkBackgroundBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
        HBRUSH hRegionOfInterestBrush = CreateSolidBrush(transparentColor);

        RECT screenRect;
        screenRect.left = screenRect.top = 0;
        screenRect.right = DesktopWidth;
        screenRect.bottom = DesktopHeight;

        RECT interestRect;
        interestRect.left = interestRect.top = 300;
        interestRect.right = interestRect.bottom = 600;
        FillRect(hdc,&screenRect,hDarkBackgroundBrush);
        FillRect(hdc,&interestRect,hRegionOfInterestBrush);

        DeleteObject(hDarkBackgroundBrush);
        DeleteObject(hRegionOfInterestBrush);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    else if (message == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clay, that makes sense but I'm struggling putting some sample code together to do it. I've got the transparent window but am stuck on where to go from here. It has been way too long since I've done any low level Windows graphics coding and it was never a strong point of mine.

Comment: Alright, I'll post a complete sample as another answer to this same question.

Comment: There's a complete example, nevf. Whew. Hope that helps.

Comment: Clay, thanks so much for that. Would you be able to send me the include files, or better still the complete project. You can e-mail me at subs@surfulater.com

Comment: Clay, don't worry about the other files as I have it working and it looks like it will do precisely what I want. Please e-mail me anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The official way is with FadeWindow() api :
Windows does that on Display Control Panel

[See the standard code in C](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/topics?gvc=2&pli=1)

Comment: Thanks, but I can find any FadeWindow() api in Windows. I have searched VS2008 Help and MSDN. I did find an article at the site you linked to which used SetLayeredWindowAttributes() which is what Clay suggested above. This works well to fade a Window, but you can't then do any normal drawing on the Window as that is faded as well.

Comment: You can re-ask on the win32 group, as it's a classic question (the api must be called by ordinal number)