# How to show semitransparent window above all windows?

Tags: c#, python, c++, windows, opengl

How to show semitransparent window above all windows? And to load some info in this window: image/text/button? I need to show some semitransparent region above all desctop table in windows/linux (or at least windows), and in the center of that region I need to show some image with text. But with all that it must not take focus of the current working application. It will be hidden automatically.
Please see images: normal desctop and the semitransparent window I want to make. 
Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want your solution to be written in C#? (it's acceptable? )

Comment: Yes, I think it would be good.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, this is the code that does what you need:

Note: It does not steel focus on startup and it does not steel focus when clicking on it.

```
public static class ExtendedWindowStyles
{

    public static readonly Int32

    WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES = 0x00000010,

    WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000,

    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x00000200,

    WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000,

    WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP = 0x00000400,

    WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT = 0x00010000,

    WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x00000001,

    WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000,

    WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = 0x00400000,

    WS_EX_LEFT = 0x00000000,

    WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR = 0x00004000,

    WS_EX_LTRREADING = 0x00000000,

    WS_EX_MDICHILD = 0x00000040,

    WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000,

    WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT = 0x00100000,

    WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY = 0x00000004,

    WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,

    WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW = WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST,

    WS_EX_RIGHT = 0x00001000,

    WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR = 0x00000000,

    WS_EX_RTLREADING = 0x00002000,

    WS_EX_STATICEDGE = 0x00020000,

    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080,

    WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008,

    WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020,

    WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE = 0x00000100;

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = true;
    }

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var currentParameters = base.CreateParams;

            currentParameters.ExStyle |= (int)(ExtendedWindowStyles.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | ExtendedWindowStyles.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);

            return currentParameters;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ClientSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        this.Left = 0;
        this.Top = 0;
        this.Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Put on your form whatever additional controls you want / need (images, labels, whatever).

You just have to pop this form from your application code by using form.ShowDialog ();. If you want to pop this form from whatever place, make it an executable and run it whenever you need it.

Comment: Thank you, but I also need the general view with semitransparent color, and above it popup. From the solution you gave me - I have only window which is top most, but it's still has head/borders/buttons. How to remove it? http://prntscr.com/8dkkqo   Maby you know other ways to do it? Maby with directX/openGL? Can I load image to some form using only directX/openGL? And not using Forms.

Comment: And this variant is more close to solution, but how to make it such a way that windows under this our semitransparent top most screen were editable and clickable? http://prntscr.com/8dkvvw